# Calculating the centralizer of a matrix in a general linear group.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $G = GL(3,\mathbb{R})$ be the general linear group over the reals , of order $3$ , and let 
$A\in G$ be :

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\\
 0 & 1  & 0 \\\
 0 &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I'm having a hard time calculating $C(A)$ , I've deduced the following :

$$C(A)=\langle A \rangle \cup \{ kI | k \in R , k \neq 0 \}$$

Is there any other elements in $C(A)$? and how do I go about solving such a question?

Note : $\langle A \rangle$ is the cyclic sub-group of $G$, generated by $A$

Comment: @julien ,@anon I appreciate your answers , however , the suggested solutions are from linear algebra's perspective , I was looking for a solution from the abstract algebra perspective.
Here's what I was considering : showing a homomorphism from G to itself , and the calculating the kernel of the mapping , which is a normal sub group of G.
I though that the mapping would be defined as follows :
f : G -> G , f(g)=AgA^(-1) , g in G .

Comment: The answer is not: the cyclic subgroup generated by $A$ union invertible scalar matrices. Ignoring the linear algebraic structure under this group question is not a very good idea. No matter what you do, you will need some linear algebra at some point.

Answer (score 8):

If $B$ commutes with $A$, it leaves the eigenspaces of $A$ invariant. In this case, these are the one-dimensional subspaces generated by the vectors of the canonical basis $\{e_i\;;\; i=1,2,3\}$. So $Be_i=\lambda_ie_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. That is $B$ is diagonal. The converse is clear.

**Conclusion:** the commutant of $A$ in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ is the subalgebra of diagonal matrices. And the centralizer of $A$ in $GL(3,\mathbb{R})$ is therefore the subgroup of invertible diagonal matrices.

**Note:** this observation generalizes to any diagonal matrix with pairwise distinct diagonal elements. It generalizes also to a any (diagonalizable) matrix with pairwise distinct eigenvalues: the commutant is then the subalgebra of matrices which are simultaneuously diagonalizable with $A$. As soon as the eigenspaces become bigger, the commutant loses its commutativity.

**Edit:** for more "abstract-algebra", I will add that the commutant of $A$ is, in this case, $\mathbb{R}[A]=\{p(A)\;;\; p\in\mathbb{R}[X]\}$ the algebra of all polynomial evaluations on $A$. It follows from the above after you have observed that, by interpolation, for any $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$, there exists a polynomial of degree $2$ $p(X)$ such that $p(-1)=\lambda_1, p(1)=\lambda_2, p(2)=\lambda_3$. In particular $\mathbb{R}[A]=\mathbb{R_2[A]}$ is three-dimensional. Ththe latter can be recovered directly from the minimal polynomial.

So the centralizer is $\mathbb{R}[A]^*=\{B=p(A)\;;\; \det B\neq 0\}=\{B=p(A)\;;\; p(-1)p(1)p(2)\neq 0\}$. It is interesting to think about this result in view of the functional calculus and the spectral mapping theorem.

Comment: "the centralizer of $A$ in $\GL_n(3,\mathbb{R})$ is therefore the subgroup of invertible diagonal matrices." you mean that the union of all the centralizers is the regular diagonal subgroup or that every $A$ has the same centralizer?

Answer (score 5):

A matrix $B$ commutes with $A$ iff $AB=BA$ iff $B=ABA^{-1}$; fill the entries of $B$ with unknowns, write out this equation, and then find an equivalent system of relations for the unknowns:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}a & -b & -c/2 \\ -d & e & f/2 \\ -2g & 2h & i\end{pmatrix} $$

$$\implies b,c,d,f,g,h=0,~\text{ no restrictions on }a,e,i.$$

Hence the centralizer is precisely the subgroup of invertible diagonal matrices.